# kdb+ historical database partitioning design - daily data on thousands of symbols

Tags: database-design, kdb

What would be the optimal partitioning (if any) of `kdb+` database storing daily price/return data on `10,000` symbols (e.g. stocks, indices, ETFs)?

We are talking about  `25` years of daily data (median) per symbol (`25 * 200 = 5,000 records`). So the overall size will be `10,000` symbols x `5,000` days = `50,000,000` records.

The database will *write* a new price for each symbol at the end of the day.

The most typical query will be to *read* the whole daily price history for a subset (10s even 100s) of symbols into the memory for further time series analysis/portfolio simulation.

I was thinking about partitioning by symbol, but didn't find anyone on the web doing it that way, so not sure if this is the best idea.
I've found plenty of solutions for higher-than-daily frequency where they partition tick data by **day** (each date has own partition, e.g. `2015-02-12`), or partition by **symbol range** (e.g. `ABC DEF GHI ...`), but not by **individual symbols**.

In the backtesting/portfolio simulation application<sup>[1]</sup>, I suspect that partitioning by individual symbols may have some later advantages by being able to calculate price transformations (such as moving average or RSI) in parallel by giving each worker node it's own symbol to process. On the contrary, partitioning by day/week/year instead would not provide that advantage.

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>Which is essentially first loop each symbol and pre-process its time-series into transformed time series to generate signal (e.g. calculate moving average of price). Then loop day-by-day in a path-dependent (where portfolio is a stateful object) fashion to check and act upon signals each day</sub>

Comment: 50 million rows is not much for most relational databases.  Since you don't name a particular relational database, the only answer is to test with no partitioning, then test by partitioning on symbol, day, symbol range, or whatever else you think might work.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc the point is to get my foot in the kdb+ door first and then eventually, if business need be, be able to scale up to more symbols (up to million) and gradually higher frequencies (up to 5 seconds) with the same infrastructure. That and the time series columnar nature is why kdb+ and not relational databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GilbertLeBlanc says, 50m is certainly not much and if that was the expected size it would simply be best (in this use-case) to splay the table (i.e. no partioning at all) along with using attributes on the columns that you will use for filtering (`p# or`g# on ticker since you'll be filtering on that, taking care to maintain those attributes in the event of new data being upserted). But obviously the splay table approach won't scale well if you do plan to scale it much (beyond 100m rows).

Date partitioning would be a bad idea if you primarily plan to search for *all* historic data for a particular sym (since the query will have to trawl through every date partition = many many disk reads).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Could I still efficiently employ parallel computing on selected symbols when I go for unpartitioned table with `\`p#sym` and `\`s#date`? Also, common post-processing step needed is to align the selected symbols by date (kind of `asof` self join?) to fill missing observations with previous values - LOCF, if you could comment on that

Comment: Parallel processing would still be possible yes, but parallelising in kdb is strict and not always quicker - sometimes the overhead of passing the data to the threads outweighs the parallelisation benefits (depends on various factors). In your case, parallelising each symbol might be effective, you'd have to test it. If parallelising each date then date partitioned might be better suited. As for the LOCF, I imagine you could generate a table of all possible dates, left join the data for the dates that you have (keyed on date) then use http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/fills to carry forward